# Distorted exported georeferenced tif from far north

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm trying to export a tif file for R, to plot my data on top of.

I have geo-referenced this tiff [file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k1ftuy8p0lsv89z/AAAO3oFm95CSMLS6IYsSxT6ma?dl=0): "background_changed" from "Background". But when i export it, the file is very compressed in height (because it's from far north) and I do not know how to get around this?

Comment: What coordinate system are you using. If geographic, perhaps a planar projection would work better?

Comment: I'm using lat/lon and WGS84. this is how my coordinates in the data table is provided, by planar, do you mean somthing like UTM? If I change it, I would have to figure out how to convert the data tables lat/lon as well right?

Comment: I do mean something like UTM. I don't understand what a data table has to do with a tif file? Is it a different layer? You could project both datasets if necessary or projection on the fly could take care of having other data match the image (just check the box that says "Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation" in QGIS).